# How to create dynamic links for my website while using firebase realtime-database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dynamic

I have a website, more like a blog site but not a blog site. It uses firebase realtime-database to store data for each post, but all the posts load on the same page. I want that I can share the link for my each post, so that whenever a user click on that certain link, He will be redirected to the post. But for now there is no way to do that. Can anyone help me in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Which framework are you using to display your website.
Because the way to do it depends on the framework of your choice.

But the basics are the same for everyone one of the JS-based frameworks.

You need a unique key to the post as a part of your URL, which is not necessarily a query param. you can have it as context path.

In the case of angular it generally

> {type of the page}/:id

where

> :id

refers to a unique id and all the URLs in this scheme will call to the same page but show different URLs.

Similarly, in the case of React.JS you can add them to the router, in Next.JS you have inbuilt dynamic URL binding

Now you need to fetch the data based on the post's context path/unique id.

Comment: I am new to web development so, I don't know much about it. But I have downloaded my website information using an online tool and you can check the info here. [My Website Info](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-38KKabfCt_U8mYL2kH7Qlf6TcRt693r/view?usp=sharing). Can you please guide me further on it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL you are going to add to your website so that I can give you a method to achieve what you want? Here I can see you are using vanilla js and HTML 5. so most of the routing-related work needs to be handled at the web server layer. JS will help to get the context path and and fetch the data

Comment: I want to add the url in this form `https://scriboscope.com/dynamic-link` like in this format.

Comment: I have to add the dynamic link like the above one.